# How to check if Google Maps JavaScript API is supported?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, internet-explorer-9

Google Maps JavaScript API is no longer supported in IE9. When I open my map in IE9 it shows a map without markers and a popup informing about support.

I don't need a map without markers. How can I disable it (at least - display: none) for such browsers?

There was GBrowserIsCompatible(), but it has been removed from v3...

Answer (score 0):

Just a workaround:

Check via `querySelector` if the map contains the bar with the message:

```
  google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map,'idle',function(){
   if(this.getDiv().querySelector('.infomsg a[href="https://whatbrowser.org"]')){
     this.getDiv().parentNode.removeChild(this.getDiv());
   }
  });
```

Comment: I've implemented the same workaround, but the map blinks when the page is loaded. So I had to manipulate opacity: set opacity: 0 at the very beginnig and reset it back to 1 if there is no such message.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the info message, just by using the single CSS line.

`.infomsg {display:none;}`

Comment: I wrote that "I don't need a map without markers". So even If I hide the message, there would be totally useless map.